# Best way to handle value tied to conditional

Tags: javascript

In a function I have I try to take a value, and if the value ends up as `undefined`, then I call the same function but with a different parameter

```
let price = await getPrice(name, category, '1');

if (price === undefined) {
   price = await getPrice(name, category, '2');

   if (price === undefined) {
      price = await getPrice(name, category, '3');
   }
}
```

I'm told that this approach can be very error prone, and after a bit of analyzing, I can see why. However, I don't know if there's a better way to handle this.

I need the third parameter since I use it to process a URL, as that URL has one of those strings.

```
static getPrice(productName, productCategory, variantNumber) {
 ...
 let url = `https://exampleurl.com/${productName}cat=${productCategory}${variantNumber}`;
 ...
}
```

Comment: How exactly is it "error prone"? Note that you can write that as a `while` loop instead of the sequence of nested conditionals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a loop and stop when you get a defined result.

```
const variants = ['1', '2', '3'];
let price;
for (let i = 0; i < variants.length; i++) {
  price = await getPrice(name, category, variants[i]);
  if (price !== undefined) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: This would work as expected. If you want you can use while loop instead